# How to make MySQL procedure detect error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a stored proc which inputs a invoice no. and a date and attempts to update the date to a table row. If successful it should return 1 and if failed 0. My code is below. What I get is it always returns 1 but only updates the table if the date is valid.
I want it to return 0 if the update was not successful. Appreciate any help, thanks.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `invoice_paid_date`(`inv_no` INT,    
     `date_paid` DATE)
  RETURNS SMALLINT
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  CONTAINS SQL
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  COMMENT 'attempt to update paid_date in table invoice'
BEGIN
   declare exit handler for sqlwarning, sqlexception  return 0;
   update invoice set paid_date = date_paid where invoice_no = inv_no;
return 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `invoice_paid_date`(`inv_no` INT,    
         `date_paid` DATE)
      RETURNS SMALLINT
      LANGUAGE SQL
      DETERMINISTIC
      CONTAINS SQL
      SQL SECURITY DEFINER
      COMMENT 'attempt to update paid_date in table invoice'
    BEGIN
       DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 1;
       DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SQLWARNING
       BEGIN
           SET id = 0;
           RETURN 0;
       END;

       IF id = 1 THEN
           update invoice set paid_date = date_paid where invoice_no = inv_no;
           return 1;
       END IF;
    END
```